# blocked by CORS policy issue .net MVC

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, frameworks, policy

`Hi All,

I have tried all possible ways but still not able to resolve this issue

Error : Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'Redirection URL' (redirected from 'Application URL') from origin 'Application URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

I have set below configuration
1.Add below in web config file

`````
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <remove name="Server" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol> ````

Also tried below one 
```<httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>```
  
2. ```public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

            // check for preflight request
            if (request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
                response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, X-RequestDigest, Cache-Control, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Session, odata-version");
                response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

                response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                if (request.HttpMethod == "POST")
                {
                    response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
                    response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, X-RequestDigest, Cache-Control, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Session, odata-version");
                }

                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }
        }````

Controller Method where I need to redirect from MVC controller 
 ```[System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Options)]
        [AllowCrossSiteJson]
        public ActionResult RedirectionURL()
        {
            return Redirect("https://");
        }````

In that case If solution is redirecting that time getting CORS error or solution is not able to redirect 

Please suggest me solution .
Thanks in advance
`````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.